# Update dictionary while parsing CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file like this:

```
item,#RGB
item1,#ffcc00
item1,#ffcc00
item1,#ff00cc
item2,#00ffcc
item2,#ffcc00
item2,#ffcc00
item2,#ffcc00
....
```

and I want to make dictionary `d`, with item name as key and RGB value and count as tuples in list as dictionary value, like:

```
d[item] = [ (#RGB, count) ]
```

so for "item1" as in example, I would like to get:

```
d['item1'] = [ ('#ffcc00', 2), ('#ff00cc', 1) ]
```

I imagine some Pythonic iterator can do this in one line, but I can't understand how at this moment. So far I've made this:

```
d={}
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            try:
                if d[(row[0], row[1])]:
                    i +=1
            except KeyError:
                i = 1
            d[(row[0], row[1])] = i
    except csv.Error, e:
        sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

which gives me:

```
d[(item, #RGB)] = count
```

Any better way? Or am I doing this wrongly from start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
a = {}

for row in reader:
    a.setdefault(row[0], {}).setdefault(row[1], 0)
    a[row[0]][row[1]] += 1
```

This creates a dictionary like

```
 {'item2': {'#00ffcc': 1, '#ffcc00': 3}, 
  'item1': {'#ffcc00': 2, '#ff00cc': 1}}
```

I find it more convenient than your structure, but you can convert it to tuples if needed:

```
 b = dict((k, v.items()) for k, v in a.items())
```

Comment: Beauty. Even better structure then initial. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from itertools import islice

with open('infile.txt') as f:
    d=defaultdict(Counter)
    for k,v in islice(csv.reader(f),1,None):
        d[k].update((v,))

print d
```

prints

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'item2': Counter({'#ffcc00': 3, '#00ffcc': 1}), 'item1': Counter({'#ffcc00': 2, '#ff00cc': 1})})
```